# Координаты в python

Tags: python, разработка-игр, pygame

Нужно, что бы `image3` убирался,если его координаты были равны координатом x2 , y2(координаты мишени(прямоугольник)) , как это сделать если мишень(image2) больше чем снаряд(image3).
Код:

```
import pygame , sys,time
pygame.init()
mx = 600
my = 400
playSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((mx, my))
pygame.display.set_caption("Тир")
image = pygame.image.load("tank.jpg").convert()
image = pygame.transform.scale(image, (77, 44))
image2 = pygame.image.load("cub.png").convert()
image2 = pygame.transform.scale(image2,(40,30))
image3 = pygame.image.load("Sn.png").convert()
image3 = pygame.transform.scale(image3,(20,20))
fpsController = pygame.time.Clock()
white = pygame.Color(255, 255, 255)

x = 228# Для image 
    y = 33# Для image 
    x2 = 250# image2 
    y2 = 350#image 2
    line = [[0, 200]]  # Линия 
    red = pygame.Color(255, 0, 0) # Цвета
    lightslateblue = pygame.Color(0, 200, 255) # Цвета
    move_1 = False
    move_2 = False
    move_3 = False
    move_4 = False
    p = False
    t1 = True
    t2 = False
    x3 = x #Для image3 
    y3 = y#Для image3 
    while True:

        playSurface.fill(white)
        playSurface.blit(image,[x,y])
        playSurface.blit(image2,[x2,y2])
        for element in line:
            pygame.draw.rect(playSurface, red, pygame.Rect(element[0], element[1], 900, 9))
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()




            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    #========================= Тут вам надо написать код ========================
                    x3 = x + 30
                    y3 = y + 50

                    p = True # Проверка на истинность мишени


                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                   pygame.quit()
                   sys.exit()
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    move_1 = True
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    move_2 = True


                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    move_3 = True

                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    move_4 = True

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:

                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    move_1 = False
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    move_2 = False

                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    move_3 = False


                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    move_4 = False
            #if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                #x, y = event.pos
        if move_1 == True:
            y+= 4
            if y >=170:
                y = 165

        if move_2 == True:
            x+= 4
            if x >= 895:
                x = 895
        if move_3 == True:
            y-= 4
            if y < 5:
                y = 5
        if move_4 == True:
            x-= 4
            if x < 5:
                x = 5

        if p == True:
            # ========================= И тут наверное   ========================
            playSurface.blit(image3,[x3, y3])
            y3 +=  10
            if y3 == x2 and y3  == y2  or y3 > 410:

                p = False
            y3 = y + 30
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66630/discussion-on-question-by-taras---python).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Допустим есть снаряд, который намного меньше мишени, поэтому размерами его можно пренебречь (см. [материальная точка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0) в физике). При этом фактически снаряд может быть явно не точечным, но для данной задачи все равно его размер не имеет значения. Просто мы упрощаем модель мира, чтобы уменьшить количество необходимых вычислений.

Чтобы проверить, что снаряд попал в прямоугольную мишень, достаточно проверить, что его центр находится внутри прямоугольника мишени (спасибо, кэп). Т.е. есть `x`, `y` координаты снаряда, есть `xm`, `ym` (координаты левого верхнего угла мишени), `wm`, `hw` (ширина и высота мишени). Тогда условие попадания снаряда в мишень будет выглядеть так:

```
if x >= xm and x <= xm + wm and y >= ym and y <= ym + hm:
    # действие, которое нужно выполнять, когда снаряд попал в мишень
```

Нужно учитывать, что если, например, снаряд летит слева направо, и ширина мишени меньше скорости мишени за "тик" (игровой цикл), то снаряд может пролететь сквозь мишень, не заметив ее. Тут можно или как-то просчитывать столкновение с мишенью до самого столкновения (проверять, что линия движения снаряда пересекает мишень), или просто убираем условие, что снаряд справа от мишени:

```
if x >= xm and y >= ym and y <= ym + hm:
    pass
```

Если снаряд может лететь с разных сторон от мишени, то такой способ, конечно же, не подойдет.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ , понял всё,кроме одного,как мне узнать переменную левого верхнего угла мишени?При том что я знаю только только ширину и высоту мишени.Я знаю что снаряд появляется в координатах x2 = 250,y2 = 350. А при проверке что бы мишень не уходила за края карты,мне не нужно знать координаты углов . А просто координаты самой картинки.

Comment: @Taras, я подозреваю, что `x2,y2` это и есть у вас координаты левого верхнего угла мишени.

Comment: Почитайте чуть ниже мой коментарий .

Comment: @Taras, мне не интересно разбираться в простыне вашего текста и кода.

Comment: РАБОТААЕТ! УРАА!!!!!

Comment: Как вы узнали что это верхний левый угол?????????? Что за гуру способности ???????

Comment: @Taras, когда картинка рисуется на экране, ее координаты обычно задаются ее левым верхним углом. И наоборот, когда нужно получить координаты центра картинки, к координатам угла приходится прибавлять половину размера картинки.

Comment: Спасибо огромное Вам! Если бы репутация была выше 15,поставил бы   +.